# Javascript how to convert float 2.0 to string '2.0'?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, string-formatting

I tried `toFixed()` but it's not doing what I want.
I want to have a one line code that convert

```
2.0   -->   '2.0'
2.123 -->   '2.123'
0.05  -->   '0.05'
```

Comment: What about :  .toString()

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [`Number#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
Number.prototype.toFloatString = function() {
  return this.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 1,
    maximumFractionDigits: 20 // the default is 3 if min < 3
  });
};

console.log((2.0).toFloatString());
console.log((2.123).toFloatString());
console.log((0.05).toFloatString());
```

Alternatively, just use `toString()`, and then add `.0` if the number was an integer:

```js
Number.prototype.toFloatString = function() {
  var str = this.toString();
  return str.indexOf(".") < 0 ? str + ".0" : str;
};

console.log((2.0).toFloatString());
console.log((2.123).toFloatString());
console.log((0.05).toFloatString());
```

Comment: Support for toLocaleString is very modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @epascarello I've added another answer for better compatibility.

Comment: But when you do a (2).toFloatString(), still it gives 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want `toString()` but with a minimum decimal point (1). Here's a one-liner that will do what you want.

`var num = 5;`

`num.toFixed(Math.max(1, num.toString().substr(num.toString().indexOf(".")+1).length));`

I'd rather just stick this in a function -

```
function floatToString(num) {
    return num.toFixed(Math.max(1, num.toString().substr(num.toString().indexOf(".")+1).length));
}
```

Usage:

```
floatToString(2.0)   -->   '2.0'
floatToString(2.123) -->   '2.123'
floatToString(0.05)  -->   '0.05'
```

Comment: This is doing way more work than it needs to. There are simpler answers.

Comment: @4castle The question asked for a one-liner, which neither of your answers are.

Comment: I could put all my code on one line, but I like readable code. All 3 of us have an answer that uses one semicolon. One-liners are overrated though when it doesn't make sense to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `toString()` it will produce the desired output expect for .0 floats. Therefore, you can use this function:

```
function floatToStr(num) {
    return num.toString().indexOf('.') === -1 ? num.toFixed(1) : num.toString();
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function floatToStr(num) {
    return num.toString().indexOf('.') === -1 ? num.toFixed(1) : num.toString();
}

console.log(floatToStr(2.0));
console.log(floatToStr(2.123));
console.log(floatToStr(0.05));
```